# Delete whole line if after ":" less than 4 chars

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file with many lines, such as :

```
blue:fish
red:tomato
black:moon
```

I would like the whole line to be deleted if after ":" there is less than 4 chars.

Comment: If any answer solves your issue, please consider [accepting that answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  If you're happy with an answer, accepting it and maybe even upvoting it is the best way to say "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`sed`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

```
sed -r -e '/:.{0,3}$/d' data
```

`-r` uses extended regular expressions (for `{}`). The `sed` expression matches all lines with a colon followed by zero to three characters and then the end of the line; `d` deletes those lines. All the rest will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

This AWK command splits on `:` and prints lines which of which the second field is at least 4 chars (not less than 4 chars). Assumption: `:` is always present and does not occur multiple times.

```
awk -F : "length($2) >= 4"
```

If it occurs multiple times, then you could use `$NF` instead of `$2` to refer to the last column.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do it.

Here is a `perl`:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless /:.{0,3}$/' file
blue:fish
red:tomato
black:moon
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash:

```bash
while read; do
  [[ "$REPLY" =~ :.{4,} ]] && printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
done
```

Then, redirect as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -E ':.{4,}$' file
```

Using `grep` + `sponge` (from moreutils), to "edit" file "in place":

```
grep -E ':.{4,}$' file|sponge file
```